# Is the space of all bounded linear operators form a Banach space (under the given norm)?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the class of all bounded linear operators on $X$ such that for each $f$ we have 
\begin{equation*}
m(f)=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }.
\end{equation*}
is a Banach space.

Comment: Why do you want to replace Lipschitz with continuous? Your norm only makes sense for Lipschitz functions, for example $\sqrt{x}$ is continous on $[0,1]$ but not Lipschitz so your norm, which is assigns a function its smallest Lipschitz constant, is not well defined for this function. As to why $CL^0\cap \{ f \mid f(1)≤1\}$ is closed, check that the functional $ev_1 : CL^0 \to \Bbb R, f\mapsto f(1)$ is continuous, hence $ev_1^{-1}([-1,1])$ is closed as the pre-image of a closed set. (To check continuity, note that $|ev_1(f)|=|f(1)| = \frac{|f(1)-f(0)|}{1-0} ≤ \|f\|_{CL^0}$.)

Comment: @s.harp I want to use the idea of bounded linear operators, with the fact: the constant $M$ does not depend on $v$, this shows that $L$ is uniformly continuous, and even Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @s.harp with due respect. Are you sure $\sqrt{x}$ is a bounded linear operator (under the given norm)? Also, as we are considering functions on $[0,1]$, then why preimage will be $ev_{1} ^{-1}([-1,1])$ ??? can you please explain. Thanks

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are trying to do. But at any rate: If $X, Y$ are two normed spaces then the space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$, $B(X,Y)$, is also a normed space, with norm given by the smallest Lipschitz constant of the operators. This space is Banach _if and only if_ $Y$ is Banach (it doesn't matter what $X$ is). So if $Y$ is Banach then $B(X,Y)$ is Banach, if $Y$ is not Banach then $B(X,Y)$ is not Banach.

Comment: @s.harp Please check the above statement. I modified it. Now, please guide me whether the statement is true or not?